# Python: Turtle module won't run my code on Python 3.6

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm doing some practice problems where I write code so turtle can draw a square, circle, polygon, etc. The issue is that when I try to run my code, turtle is either:

1. Not responding and I have to force close it
2. Only runs the part of my code that draws a square

I'm using Python 3.6 on Spyder and have tried using `turtle.mainloop()` and `turtle.done()` at the end of each section but I keep running into the same problem.

Here is my code:

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
print(bob)

bob.fd(100)
bob.lt(90)
bob.fd(100)
bob.lt(90)
bob.fd(100)
bob.lt(90)
bob.fd(100)
turtle.done()


for i in range(4):
    print("Hello!")

for i in range(4):
    bob.fd(100)
    bob.lt(90)
turtle.done()

t = turtle.Turtle()
def square(t):
    print(t)
    t.fd(100)
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(100)
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(100)
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(100)
    t.lt(90)
turtle.done()

square(bob)
turtle.done()

t = turtle.Turtle()
def square(t):
    print(t)
    for i in range(4):
        t.fd(100)
        t.lt(90)
turtle.mainloop()
turtle.done()


t = turtle.Turtle()
def square(t, length):
    print(t)
    for i in range(4):
        t.fd(length)
        t.lt(90)

square(t, 200)

turtle.done()


t = turtle.Turtle()
def polygon(t, length, n):
    print(t)
    for i in range(4):
        t.fd(length)
        t.lt(360/n)

polygon(t, t = 200, n = 12)
turtle.done()

import math

def circle(t, r):
    circumference = 2 * math.pi * r
    n = 100
    length = circumference / n
    polygon(t, length, n)

circle(t, 100)
turtle.done()
"""draws a circle in turtle"""
```

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  Pare this down to just enough code to illustrate the problem: maybe only two shape routines, with each being a simple angle.  Include some `print` commands to track your program flow.

Comment: [`turtle.done()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.done) must be the last statement in a turtle graphics program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiple `turtle.done()` statements, when there should only be one, and the fact that the various pieces of code don't take into account where the other pieces of code have drawn, make this look like it should be a collection of individual programs in individual files:

Program 1:

```
import turtle

bob = turtle.Turtle()
print(bob)

bob.fd(100)
bob.lt(90)
bob.fd(100)
bob.lt(90)
bob.fd(100)
bob.lt(90)
bob.fd(100)

for i in range(4):
    print("Hello!")

turtle.done()
```

Program 2:

```
import turtle

bob = turtle.Turtle()

for i in range(4):
    bob.fd(100)
    bob.lt(90)

turtle.done()
```

Program 3:

```
import turtle

def square(t):
    print(t)
    t.fd(100)
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(100)
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(100)
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(100)
    t.lt(90)

bob = turtle.Turtle()

square(bob)

turtle.done()
```

Program 4:

```
import turtle

def square(t):
    print(t)
    for i in range(4):
        t.fd(100)
        t.lt(90)

t = turtle.Turtle()

square(t)

turtle.mainloop()
```

Program 5:

```
import turtle

def square(t, length):
    print(t)
    for i in range(4):
        t.fd(length)
        t.lt(90)

t = turtle.Turtle()

square(t, 200)

turtle.done()
```

Program 6:

```
import turtle
import math

def polygon(t, length, n):
    print(t)
    for i in range(n):
        t.fd(length)
        t.lt(360 / n)

t = turtle.Turtle()
polygon(t, length=50, n=12)

def circle(t, r):
    """draws a circle in turtle"""
    circumference = 2 * math.pi * r
    n = 100
    length = circumference / n
    polygon(t, length, n)

circle(t, 100)

turtle.done()
```

Try running these as separate programs in separate files and see if turtle works any better for you.

Answer (score 0):

<del>You're telling the computer how to do things, but you never actually tell it *to* do them. Run `circle(t)` etc. to do this.</del>

You're not consistently running all the things you want to. Read through your code carefully and make sure you're always running `mainloop` etc..